# Post title not output correctly

Tags: seo

I am trying to set up titles of posts with WordPress SEO, however my title gets output like this:

My post name

There is no separator and site name.

Here's the code in the theme:

```
  <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

In the WordPress SEO settings, under Post Types > Posts I have the following setting for titles:

%%title%% %%page%% %%sep%% %%sitename%%

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the WordPress SEO FAQ](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/faq/):

... either enable "Force rewrite titles" on the SEO -> Titles settings page, or go into your header.php and change the title element to just this:

```
<title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>
```

Did you try that?

Comment: +1. The only thing that should *ever* be inside the HTML `<title></title>` tags is `<?php wp_title(); ?>` (with or without args). Plugins use the `wp_title` filter to modify the output of `wp_title()`, and Themes should do likewise, in order to play nicely with SEO Plugins.

Comment: Tried both of those but it still didn't change it to what I want.

Comment: Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Don't know why people vote down this question, I can see why you had that code (which you now have removed) cause it's what is used in the default themes; Twentyeleven and Twentytwelve etc. However, if you want a separator you need to add that to the wp_title function:

`<title><?php wp_title('|'); ?></title>`

Comment: Also, try to restore default settings if you haven't already.

Comment: Would that also give me the sitename after the postname?

Comment: Yeah it works for me, I'm just using the default settings. My home page is a static page though, so I don't know how the default index page acts but all pages should display the sitename in the title by default. Maybe there's something weird with your sitename, special characters etc?